# Help to prove an inequality not by math induction

Tags: limits, inequality

Can someone help to prove the inequality from below? Not by math induction.

$\frac 1 2 \times \frac 3 4 \times \dots \times \frac {2n-1} {2n}$ < $\frac {1} {\sqrt{2n-1}}$

Comment: I upvoted to reverse the downvote, not because I think that the query doesn't need improvement, but because you are a new user, who should be given pointers on how to improve your query and time to make the improvements.  Please see the following links: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 12\frac 34\cdot...\cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}=
\frac 12\frac22\frac 34\frac44\cdot...\cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}\frac{2n}{2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!n!}$$

Now use [Stirling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: re my comments to the original query, how do you know that the teacher/book author intended that the student be aware of the Stirling formula.

Comment: @user2661923: I assume (since the OP did not say otherwise) that it is a competition problem. People who participate in these competitions must know the Stirling formula.

Comment: I was hoping that you would consider that the OP is supposed to provide background and show work before receiving an answer.  This is not my arbitrary policy.

Comment: @user2661923: That is correct.  The OP seems to be unaware of it. You should post a comment to the question.

Comment: Did you check the comments under the query before posting?  Note the time-stamp of my comment and the time-stamp of your answer.

Comment: @user2661923: There are two comments below the question. Yes, I looked at them. You seem to imply that you put another comment there. Where is it?

Comment: My comment was the first one posted.  You can verify that by looking at the signature of that comment and the signature of *this* comment.

Comment: @user2661923: Now I see that the first comment there is yours. You write that you upvoted the question, and then give some links. Right? This comment says nothing about the answer.

Comment: When you say "you looked at them" do you mean that you actually examined the underlying links?

Comment: Yes, and I explained why.  Before I got there, somebody gave an *anonymous* downvote, with no explanation.

Comment: @user2661923: Your comment was addressed to the OP. If it was addressed to me and was about my answer, I would gladly read the links. I do not understand the purpose of this discussion. You **did not** answer this question before me. What's the complain?

Comment: The point of the links is to tell the OP what he needs to do to improve the query.  Those links become pointless if an answer is given before the OP improves the query.  Why would any OP be bothered, if he is going to be handed the answer anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113997/discussion-between-dodd-and-user2661923).